# Why one click on element of HTML, fire twice?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

This is a question asked several times and resolved.
We use

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

or

```
e.stopPropagation(); 
e.preventDefault();
```

But the main part of the question is not answered clearly...
Why does this happen? And what do these methods do to solve this?

Example :
I create this scripts and html on server side and pass it to client :

### Jquery

```
$('body').on('click', '#GridContainer tbody tr', function (e) {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
...
});
```

### HTML

```
<div id="GridContainer" class="webGridContainer">
    <table class="webgrid TestList table  selectableGrid" id="GridTestList">
        <thead class="TestListHeader">
            <tr>
                <th data-lab-name="TestId">code</th>
                <th data-lab-name="TestName">Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="TestListBody TestListAlternativeRow">
            <tr class="">
                <td data-grid-name="TestId">0</td>
                <td data-grid-name="TestName" class="TestListTestName" style="">---</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot class="TestListGridFooter"></tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

When I remove `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` Click fire twice.

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: if there are 2 event listener, One for parent and second for child. After that one performs some action on child `event` bubbles up

Comment: I edited post and put my code...

Comment: Please also add your HTML or the HTML that is used for this part. That makes it easier to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

On Chome dev tools, check `Sources > Event Listener Breakpoints > Mouse > click` and you will be able to see who's triggering this events.

Comment: My main problem is reason of these. I want prevent of this problem by my correct code if I mistake somewhere